# View Members in back office with custom Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net-membership, umbraco, umbraco7

I am using Umbraco 7.1 and I have a custom Membership Provider, which I set up following various different tutorials and blog posts. For the most part it is working well, but there are a couple of things I don't understand:

My custom Membership Provider inherits from `System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider` the majority of tutorials I have read say it should inherit from `Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.MembersMembershipProvider` but when I change it to inherit from that, the methods I have overridden are no longer hit, for example if I put a break point on `ValidateUser(string username, string password)` it will not get hit when I attempt to login. Can someone please explain which class I should inherit from and why? That would be awesome.

Secondly, I have overridden `GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)` so when I login to the back office and go to Members, I can see a list of all of the people who have registered on the site. But when I click on a member to view their details, the `GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline)` method gets hit, but the providerUserKey is always `null`. In the table my Members are saved in, I have a column for the ProviderUserKey, I have tried setting it as a UniqueIdentifier and as a string, with the same result. So if someone could tell me how to view Member details in the back office with a custom Membership Provider, I would appreciate it. I am assuming this is possible, but I could well be wrong.

Any help at all greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Jim you should inherit from

> Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.MembersMembershipProvider

instead of

> System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider

for sure. I have done that and it works. You must be doing something else wrong. How are you calling Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password) should be checked. refer the screenshot.[image]

For getting all members in backend, I have not done that but you must override getallusers, something like mentioned below.

```
public override System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        //create collection
        var collection = new MembershipUserCollection();
        // fetch members from my logic.
        //also add those to collection


        //get default members and add to collection.
        var coll2 = base.GetAllUsers(pageIndex, pageSize, out totalRecords);
        foreach (MembershipUser a in coll2)
        {
            collection.Add(a);
        }

        return collection;
    }
```